# Are/is "headquarters" always used as plural?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I'm studying *Intelligent Business English*, there is a question like this:

> ... The company has offices in six countries, but the -------- are in
> Brussels.
>
> a. headquarters
>
> b. main
>
> c. bank
>
> d. house

I think b, c and d don't make sense, so a is the answer. But the word is "are", which means it is a plural. I looked up a source:

- My dictionary tells it is always plural.
- This discussion: ([Link too long, please click here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=793471)),

So, in most cases, which type is *headquarters?* Plural or singular?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nouns that look like plurals, because they end in *-s*, but whose meaning is collective or composite,  are known as ‘pluralia tantum’. *Headquarters* is one such, and *premises, surroundings* and *outskirts* are others. *Headquarters* is unusual in that it can be followed either by a singular or by a plural verb.

*Quarters* alone can mean almost any place of residence, including the place where troops are lodged. [Ngrams shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quarters%20is,quarters%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) quite a wide disparity in favour of *quarters are* over *quarters is* and a cursory look at the citations in the OED suggests that *quarters* in this sense is treated as plural. The OED’s earliest citation for *headquarters* is dated 1660: ‘The head-quarters of the Army were at Windsor.’ This suggests that the longer word took on the grammatical number of the shorter. The earliest citation for *headquarters is* is from 1937. The change may have come about through the perception that *headquarters* is a recognisably single place in a way that *premises, surroundings* and *outskirts* are not.

Comment: This is not correct. Pluralia tantum are truly plural, meaning they must agree with plural verb forms and determiners. Eg: Shenanigans **beget** shenanigans. / His antics **are** exhausting. / **Those** pants **look** so garish. Words like **headquarters**, **works**, **crossroads**, **sheep**, **moose** are merely *morphologically invariable*, meaning that their singular and plural forms are *identical*. Eg: **A/Five** steel works / **That/those** crossroads **was/were** often busy. / The company has **one/two** headquarters.

Answer (score 6):

*Headquarters* is not always plural, nor always singular, as noted in [your link](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=793471).  Among responses at that link, "Loob" in England writes:

> ... if I were talking about a military HQ like the one I used to work in, I would definitely use "is".
>       But for a company headquarters (= the HQ of a single company), I'm pretty sure I use both "is" and "are". I was putting this down to that free-and-easy way we Brits have with collective nouns ...

Likewise, I imagined that *headquarters is* would be found more often in British usage than American.  However, that notion is not borne out by [American-](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=headquarters%20are,headquarters%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5) and [British-](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=headquarters%20are,headquarters%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6) corpus ngrams for *headquarters are,headquarters is* :

[image: AmEng]  [image: BrEng]

As can be seen, *headquarters are* is more predominant than *headquarters is*, in both corpora, and is more markedly so in the British English corpus than in the American English corpus.  (Note, there are numerous confounding cases that ngrams does not sort out, *e.g.*  *headquarters*  appearing at the end of a sentence or phrase, and *is* or *are* starting another; or reference to multiple headquarters establishments.  However, I think those are probably a small enough fraction of instances that the general idea holds.)

Comment: Wow nice! Now I know a new Google Books feature!

Answer (score 3):

**Headquarters** is *plural noun*, but depending on the context, or better say construct, it can be used with singular or plural verb as per the dictionary.

> Google has its headquarters in Mountain View, CA (Singular)
>   Apple and Google have their headquarters in CA (Plural)

Comment: In your example, has and have relate to singular "Google" or plural "Apple and Google". The question is about which verbs to use with headquarters. For example: should we use "the headquarters are", or "the headquarters is"? The accepted answer explains that both are possible.

Comment: The question is not about "which verbs to use with headquarters". The question was whether it is singular or plural which will drive which verb will go with it.

Comment: I grant that Apple and Google have distinct and separate headquarters, but this is about using "are" or "is" with headquarters as the subject. English is an SVO language and the subject, not the object, determines the plurality of the verb. For headquarters to "drive" the verb, it should be the subject.  For instance, here is "cat" as the subject, with the verb changing accordingly : "A cat (singular subject) *has* two ears (plural object)", and  "Cats (plural subject) *have* two ears".  In both your examples, headquarters is the object and therefore doesn't influence the verb "to have".